# How to remove all window transparency effects

Tags: 18.04, window, transparency, effects

I would like to remove all transparency effects from windows in Ubuntu 18.04.
An example: If the browser is below the terminal window I can see the bookmarks bar and everyhing else through it. 
How to remove that effect?

Comment: Well one thing you could do would be to install a lighter desktop environment like LXDE.

Comment: You can set the transparency of the terminal.

Comment: @DKBose How? What about other windows like notifications, browser, files...?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the transparency on terminal of `ubuntu 18.04`, open `Preferences` of terminal (Right click and select `Preferences` or select `Preferences` from `Edit` menu) and uncheck `Use transparency from system theme` in `Colors` tab of `Profile`.